# PHP fwirte() how can I set timeout?

Tags: php, settimeout

I have a problem.

I connect a server use fsockopen and it success.

Maybe Network blocking after connect successed, so, I want to set a timeout when I use fread and fwrite.

I can set timeout with stream_set_timeout when I fread something,

and checked by stream_get_meta_data.

```
$fs = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 10008, $errno, $errstr, 1);
stream_set_timeout($fs, 5, 0);
read(1024,$fs);
function read($length, $fs)
{
    $read = 0;
    $parts = array();

    while ($read < $length && !feof($fs)) {
        $data = fread($fs, $length - $read);
        $status = stream_get_meta_data($fs);
        if ($status['timed_out']) {
            die("Stream Timeout!n");
        }
        $read += strlen($data);
        $parts []= $data;
    }
    return implode($parts);
}
```

now, I want to know, if stream_set_timeout can work in fwrite?

and, How can I set timeout when I use fwrite?

My English is so poor.sorry.

Comment: Not sure... but don't you mean sleep() instead?

Comment: I test fread by server sleep().But i don't have a method to test fwrite....